# Evaluate under Hoare logic

Tags: formal-methods, software-engineering, hoare-logic

Evaluate
WP(a = i + 2; i=i+1, ((a=6)^(i=5))
WP(x=x+1,y=y-1. (xxy>0))
wp(if x > 2 then y = 1 else y = -1,(x > 0))
wp(while n <> 0 do n:=n-1; n = 10)
wp(while n = 0 do n:=n-1; n=-10)
wp(while n <> 0 do n:=n-1; n=-10)

Comment: There is no Hoare triple anywhere in this post. Weakest precondition calculus is related to, but not equal to Hoare logic. What have you tried?